# Discord bot JDA doesn't work, caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, discord-jda

I am trying to build a discord bot with the Java Discord API, but when I run this code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
    JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
    builder.setActivity(Activity.watching("boop"));
    builder.build();
}
```

It throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/map/TLongObjectMap
at net.dv8tion.jda@4.2.0_216/net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity.watching(Activity.java:204)
at rambot/rambot.discord.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.map.TLongObjectMap
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 2 more
```

Why is this being thrown, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of JDA are you using?

Comment: I'm using JDA-4.2.0_217

Comment: Interesting. There is no code on [line 204 in Activity.java](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Activity.java#L204), nor is `TLongObjectMap` present anywhere in the class. Have you tried adding [Trove4J](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove/src/master/) to your `pom.xml`/`build.gradle`/`.classpath`? I assume you are using a linux machine?

Comment: Well,I found a solution ^^',by going to the [JDA github] (https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#noclassdeffounderror-or-classnotfoundexception-on-startup) ,If the code didn't work it's because I wasn't with the -withDependencies.jar
now I have no more problems, thank you very much for reading my post, I should have inquired a little more before asking for help

Comment: In the future, you may want to use build tools like gradle or maven. They will automatically implement all those dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

For people who see this, but can't seem to read the comments or figure it out on their own. [On the JDA wiki, there is an explanation as well](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19-Troubleshooting#noclassdeffounderror-or-classnotfoundexception-on-startup). Credits to [@BENRABAH Brahim Zaky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14650381/benrabah-brahim-zaky)

> **NoClassDefFoundError or ClassNotFoundException on startup**
> An error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder or similar means you are not including your dependencies or transitive dependencies in the archive.

> **Gradle (build.gradle)**
> With gradle this can be fixed by using the shadow plugin and building your jar with shadowJar instead. The jar will then be present in the build/libs directory with a name like example-1.0-all.jar

> **Maven (pom.xml)**
> With maven you need the shade plugin in your pom to add dependencies to your package task. You can see the shade plugin being applied in this example pom.xml

> **Jar (No build tools)**
> You need to use the `-withDependencies.jar` rather than the normal one.

The preferred method depends per programmer, but I suggest using either gradle or maven. Since they do everything from compiling your Jar to adding the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too, this error is caused since your compiler didn't found the class path

**my solution:**

you have to delete the (JDA) from **Modulepath** and add it to **Classpathh** inside the (**java build path**).